# How to copy an active excel sheet and save it into a new workbook using a vbs script?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to copy an excel sheet that includes formulas and paste it into a new excel workbook as values and retaining the format using vbs script.

I'm currently doing it but instead of copying I'm saving it as a CSV. 
So it is only saving the first page but it looses the format.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: @GTAVLover this is the code I use to Open, refresh and save as csv:

Option Explicit
Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSheet 
Const xlCSV = 6
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:filedirectory\filename.xlsx")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook.RefreshAll
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Wscript.Sleep 720000
xlbook.save
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlbook.saveas "C:filedirectory\filename.csv", xlcsv
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Quit

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around to fix this, I run a vbs to refresh and save the file. then with a batch file i run another script and open the file to only run a macro inside of it and the macro does the job.